# Setting up Android Development Environment on Windows 7

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, adt, android-sdk-2.3

I want to start learning Android developement. I have a windows 7 Home Premium Operating System. My problem is I am not able to setup the environment of developing android. Here is what I have done till now.

1. I have installed Java (both 32 bit and 64 bit versions)
2. I have installed Android SDK (installer_r08-windows.exe)
3. I have not yet downloaded any tools or platforms or ADT.
4. I have downloaded 32 bit eclipse. (eclipse-SDK-3.5.1-win32.zip)
5. I am stuck at this eclipse setup. A strange thing I observed is that, it does not install. When I click on eclipse.exe, it starts running from there only. I am still not sure if my eclipse installation is proper?
6. So, I assumed that my eclipse is working fine. Then when I try installing new programs in eclipse, eg google plugin, it gives error.

I want to know, where am I going wrong? What mistakes am I doing? 
Can anyone guide me with the complete step by step procedure to setup my android development environment on windows 7?

Thanks in advance.

- Jay

Comment: There is no install eclipse; you download the zip, and copy it to where you want it to run from. If you use Chrome or IE, you'll need to "unblock" the .exe files.

Comment: Maybe this video helps you out: [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIL1UouA4dE&feature=player_embedded#!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIL1UouA4dE&feature=player_embedded#!)

Answer (score 1):

to 5: Eclipse don't have a normal installer, its just a zip file you can extract and run from anywhere.

to 6: What errors do you get? (I will update my answer when you deliver more details)

A step by step how to is here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting errors like "No repository found" and "cannot complete install", etc.

Comment: Also, I am using IE as my browser.

Comment: You should follow the steps and you should tell us exactly at which point you get this error message. Probably you can find questions and solutions here on stackoverflow, just search or ask if you can't find anything

Answer (score 1):

I found I had to relax Windows 7's security settings quite a lot just until Eclipse was fully set up, and then I was able to restore them back to their normal setting.

Answer (score 1):

I want to share my experience of installing environment in windows 7 ultimate.

*** I have faced problem with both the version of JAVA 32 bit and 64 bit (I may be wrong). After deleting 32 bit my problem was solved at first time.

*** Maximum learner mistake to ensure properly their android environment variables.

So, hope you will ensure that above two problem.

Here I have attached a link where proper installing method has been given with image marking. So, I hope it will help you to setup environment properly.

http://sanathnandasiri.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-setup-android-development.html

Thanks for your important time.